# C# if statement within Javascript, Razor/MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have the following variable that work very well on the code bellow, but I would like to add an if/else statement and I'm having some issue with the formatting. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Before:

```
     var originalSales = {  
     "RenewalDate":  validateDefaultDateValue('@(Model.Program.RenewalDate.HasValue ?
      Model.Program.RenewalDate.Value.AddYears(1).ToString("g") : "" )'),}
```

What I'm trying to Accomplish:

```
     var originalSales = { 
    "RenewalDate": validateDefaultDateValue(@if((Model.Program.IsNonServiceYear) && 
    (Model.ProgramCode.HasAutoRenewDate == true))
  {('@(Model.Program.RenewalDate.HasValue ? Model.Program.RenewalDate.Value.AddYears(1).ToString("g") : "" )'),}
    else 
  {('@(Model.Program.RenewalDate.HasValue ? Model.Program.RenewalDate.Value.ToString("g") : "" )'),}),
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
@{ 
    if ( Model.Program.IsNonServiceYear && Model.ProgramCode.HasAutoRenewDate )
    {
        originalSales =x;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        originalSales =y;
    }
}
```